# Using Django OAuth toolkit on custom views

Tags: python, django, oauth

I've been using the Django OAuth toolkit to restrict access to my API. The problem is I'm not sure how to use it for my own views. It has it's own built-in "Application" views that I can see it works for but not sure how it can work for mine.

I tried using their generic classes (https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views/class_based.html) but to no avail:

views.py:

```
class PostCarFax(ReadWriteScopedResourceMixin, ProtectedResourceView):
    queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarFaxSerializer
```

This gives me a `AttributeError: type object 'PostCarFax' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'` error

I wonder if it's the way it defines it's URLs? From their code:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views


app_name = "oauth2_provider"


base_urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^authorize/$", views.AuthorizationView.as_view(), name="authorize"),
    url(r"^token/$", views.TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
    url(r"^revoke_token/$", views.RevokeTokenView.as_view(), name="revoke-token"),
    url(r"^introspect/$", views.IntrospectTokenView.as_view(), name="introspect"),
]


management_urlpatterns = [
    # Application management views
    url(r"^applications/$", views.ApplicationList.as_view(), name="list"),
    url(r"^applications/register/$", views.ApplicationRegistration.as_view(), name="register"),
    url(r"^applications/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$", views.ApplicationDetail.as_view(), name="detail"),
    url(r"^applications/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/delete/$", views.ApplicationDelete.as_view(), name="delete"),
    url(r"^applications/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/update/$", views.ApplicationUpdate.as_view(), name="update"),
    # Token management views
    url(r"^authorized_tokens/$", views.AuthorizedTokensListView.as_view(), name="authorized-token-list"),
    url(r"^authorized_tokens/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/delete/$", views.AuthorizedTokenDeleteView.as_view(),
        name="authorized-token-delete"),
]
```

I guess I could define my own views there? Here's my urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'post_carfax', views.PostCarFax)
admin.autodiscover()

from rest_framework import generics, permissions, serializers

from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
]
```